# alert is not part of Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I read about general **Introduction to Object Oriented JavaScript** from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript. 
They mentioned **alert is not part of the javascript itself.**

Is that true? Then how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several parts to the programmability of a browser:

1. The javascript language itself which has nothing specifically to do with a browser - it's a pure language.  This is described by the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and includes only the pure language and objects that are part of the language.
2. The DOM and it's programming access (such as the properties and methods of the various HTML elements).
3. The various host objects such as `window`, `window.location` or `window.navigator` and the properties and methods that they offer.  This is where `alert()` is added.

So, `alert()` is not part of the actual javascript language itself.  For example, when you use javascript server-side, there is no `alert()` method.

Comment: Thanks. your answer somewhat given about Javascript. But still I can't understand fully. Can you please explain with any-other way?

Comment: @Natesan - Javascript is an independent specification from a browser or HTML.  The actual language is only a subset of the programmability in a browser (e.g. the browser adds many additional objects that you can program that are not part of the actual javascript language specification).  What is it about my answer that you don't understand?

Comment: the browser adds many additional objects that you can program. I can Understand now. Thanks

Comment: `alert()` is a DOM method, not a JavaScript method. It won't work without a browser.

Answer (score 0):

alert is part of operating system and `alert()` is javascript function which call the `window's alert` dialog box.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.alert